# Java Swing to RTMP for flash

Tags: java, swing, screenshot, flv, flash-media-server

Is there any java program which can capture desktop screen and send it to rtmp server from which my flash program will display the captured screen..

I tried VH Java Media Toolkit but there is no download link and no files for java swing.

And if possible to convert the captured screen to .flv.

Thanks.

Comment: *"capture desktop screen"*  Once or many times?  If once, I'd recommend sending a JPEG or PNG rather than an FLV.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention screen sharing.. many times...

Comment: [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) can do something like that via FFmpeg. Does that sound acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

There is a list of potential solutions at the bottom of [this](http://wiki.xuggle.com/Xuggle_Screensharing_Notes) page, an example of which appears to be something called [red5](http://www.red5.org/) which looks fairly appropriate.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you very much elias.. but nothing worked out bcz these links provide info for applet but not for java swing... and my streaming server is flash media server... so cant use red5 here...

Comment: *"..applet but not for java swing."*  1) You've not heard of a Swing based `JApplet`?  2)  Almost anything an applet can do, can be done in a free-floating app. (and done simpler).